# Width for table columns will not set

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

If you look at all of my `<th>` tags in the `<thead>` tag in the table, you can see if each `<th>` has its own class: col1, col2, col3 and col4.

I am trying to set a max and min width for each of those classes, the problem is that it is not setting the width at all. If set the width using percentage then it doesn't work, but it does work using px, but I want to use percentage, so why is it not setting the width?

Below is table code:

```
<div id="tableWrapper">
  <div id="tableScroll">
    <table id="qandatbl" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col2">Question No</th>
          <th class="col4">Question</th>
          <th class="col2">Option Type</th>
          <th class="col1">Duration</th>
          <th class="col2">Weight(%)</th>
          <th class="col1">Answer</th>
          <th class="col3">Video</th>
          <th class="col4">Audio</th>
          <th class="col3">Image</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody> 
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is css;

```
#qandatbl{
  font-size:14px;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
}
.col1{
  background-color:#FCF6CF; 
  max-width:7%;
  min-width:7%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col2{
  background-color:#FEFEF2;
  max-width:7%;
  min-width:7%;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}   
.col3{
  background-color:#FEFEF2; 
  max-width:16%;
  min-width:16%;    
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col4{
  background-color:#FCF6CF;
  max-width:16%;
  min-width:16%;    
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#tableWrapper {
  position:relative;
}
#tableScroll {
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;  
  margin-top:20px;
}
#tableWrapper thead tr {
  position:absolute;
  top:-24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- set a width for the table

2- adjust your percentages so that their sum is 100% (taking into account the number of times each type of column appears, which seems to be twice each).

Comment: I put them all 25% to make it 100% for the total sum of the width but i did not work, it makes the headings a little wider but the whole heading doesn't go as wide as the page. Instead it is as wide as 1/3 width of page

Comment: Try setting the width of the table. That is what the percentages are relative to. So they are probably ignored if there is no table width. Use 100% to make the table use all the space.

Comment: And each of the 4 coloumns appears twice, so 25% makes a 200% sum.

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you, does the total sum of the width have to be 100% or can it be less? what I did was that I set each column to 12.5% and the '#tableWrapper tr' to 100%, (I included th in this id and that made it work)

Comment: I believe if it is less than 100% the last column will take the missing percentage for itself. I am not sure though.